# Zend Framework 2, using select

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, zend-framework2

Here is the SQL that I need to genarate from zend ORM. Its working as a sql, but I need to recreate it from zend2 ORM, when I get data for 'type' colum, if the data is from `table1` it should retrieve `'type1'`, when it come from `table2`, it should be `'type2'`.

```
select id,'type1' as type
from table1
UNION
select id,'type2' as type
from table2 where id = 1
```

I used something like in zend2, but not giving me the right values.

```
    $select->from(array('a' => 'table1'));
    $select->columns(array(
        "id",
        "'type1'" => "type"
    ));

    $select2->from(array('t2' => 'table2'));
    $select2->columns(array(
        "id",
        "'type2'" => "type"
    ));
    $select->combine ( $select2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer,

$select->from(array('a' => 'table1'));
    $select->columns(array(
        "id",
        'type' => new Expression("'type1'")
    ));

```
$select2->from(array('t2' => 'table2'));
$select2->columns(array(
    "id",
    'type' => new Expression("'type2'")
));
$select->combine ( $select2 );
```